# Itemdata and local image

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I want to import images in React.jd component from my computer and put them in ItemData. How can I do it?

```
export const Itemdata = [
    {
        img: './image/2.jpg',
        title:"image2"
    },
    {
        img:'',
        title
    }
]
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. What you have now is broad and unclear. Familiarize yourself with the editor toolbar so you can properly format your code. Did you mean _React.js_?